# javax.json and jakarta.json in the same application: org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl cannot be cast to jakarta.json.spi.JsonProvider

Tags: java, jakarta-jsonp

I am developing an application targeting a Java EE 8 application server (JBoss/Wildfly).

However, one of the dependencies (elasticsearch api) is already using `jakarta.json.*` classes which results in a ClassCastException at runtime:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl
> cannot be cast to jakarta.json.spi.JsonProvider

That is because the `org.classfish.json.JsonProviderImpl` in my classpath (`org.classfish:javax.json:1.1.4`) is still using javax.json classes.

However, as both `org.glassfish:jakarta.json` and `org.classfish:javax.json` define the same class `org.classfish.json.JsonProviderImpl` (one using the `javax.json.*` classes and one using the `jakarta.json.*` classes...), I am unable to simply include both maven artifacts.

The implementation of JsonProviderImpl (**in both artifacts!**) basically returns the following by default:

```
return Class.forName("org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl");
```

When both `org.glassfish:jakarta.json` and `org.classfish:javax.json` are on the classpath, this will cause issue for any of the implementations which will get the `JsonProviderImpl` from the other package.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: I have created https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/issues/55 to ask specifically about the situation with Elasticsearch. However, the general issue remains whether javax.json.* and jakarta,json.* can both be used within the same application.

Comment: Can't you just pick an Elasticsearch version suitable for your environment?

Comment: @BalusC: Elasticsearch itself is already running using Java 11 and will likely be kept current. As the "old" Java REST Client is being deprecated, I would like to use the "new" Java Client for Elasticsearch from my Java application - however, Wildfly for Jakarta EE 9 is still in preview stage, so I have to use Java EE 8 for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference: [This has been fixed by the Elastic team](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/pull/63): They have switched from the Glassfish implementation

```
api("org.glassfish", "jakarta.json", "2.0.1")
```

to [Eclipse Parsson](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/parsson):

```
api("jakarta.json:jakarta.json-api:2.0.1")
api("org.eclipse.parsson:parsson:1.0.0")
```

Comment: I'm happy for a WORKAROUND, but this is clearly a workaround. The problem is, why it happens, that I add glassfish's implementation, which is implementing the proper interface and the ServiceLoader doesn't find it on the factory method? Most likely glassfish's package is missing something.

I ran into this problem but not with colliding class names, but simply updating myself on jakarta api and replacing my javax glassfish json to jakarta glassfish json

Answer (score 1):

One workaround seems to be to use the maven shade plugin to basically "rename" the package `org.glassfish.json` in the "new" `org.glassfish:jakarta.json` to `jakarta.org.glassfish.json`:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <filters>
          <filter>
            <artifact>org.glassfish:jakarta.json</artifact>
            <includes>
              <include>org/glassfish/json/**</include>
            </includes>
          </filter>
        </filters>
        <artifactSet>
          <includes>
            <include>org.glassfish:jakarta.json</include>
          </includes>
        </artifactSet>
        <relocations>
          <relocation>
            <pattern>org.glassfish.json</pattern>
            <shadedPattern>jakarta.org.glassfish.json</shadedPattern>
          </relocation>
        </relocations>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Then, one can create the file `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/jakarta.json.spi.JsonProvider` with the following content:

```
jakarta.org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl
```

This will tell the implementation of `jakarta.json.spi.JsonProvider` to use the shaded version of the `JsonProviderImpl` (from the `org.glassfish:jakarta.json` artifact - which uses the `jakarta.json.*` classes) instead of the `JsonProviderImpl` (with the same name from `org.glassfish:javax.json`).